# How can I store every character in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I want to be able to store every character possible (Chinese, Arabic, these kind of characters: `☺♀☻`) in a MySQL database and also be able to use them in PHP and HTML. how do I do this?

**Edit:** when I use the function `htmlspecialchars()` with those characters: `☺♀☻` like this: `htmlspecialchars('☺♀☻', ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');` it returns some seemingly random characters. how do I solve this?

Comment: Is this what you actually want? A massively cut-down copy of the Unicode codepoint list?

Comment: In order to clarify my point above, I'm not sure such a table would make any sense. Many codepoints are useless on their own. Some affect the text flow around the character, such as U+200E (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK) and U+200F (RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK); others change the preceding characters, such as U+0300 (COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT) and U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT). Unfortunately, storing all these in a database without the relevant metadata is practically useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8 character encoding for all text/var fields in your database, as well as page encoding. Be sure to use multibyte (mb_*) forms of text functions, such as mb_substr().

Answer (score 0):

Pick a character set that has the characters you want. utf-8 is very broad most commonly used.

Storing the characters is not so much a problem since it's all just binary data. If you also want the text to be searchable then picking the right collation is useful. `utf8_general_ci` is fine.